# Is there a way to update permissions for all google drive files at once?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to change the permissions for **all files** in a google drive of a certain employee who is leaving the company

> example1@domain.com

to another employee in the same domain

> example2@domain.com

using **Drive API**, but all I can find - even in the documentation - is to update the permissions
for file by file.

So, is there a way that I can change the permissions of the whole google drive at once?

Comment: I suggest you file it as a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106) here. If in any case, this can be done through your Google Workspace Admin Console. Check the [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247799?hl=en) here

Comment: I know it can be done through the workspace admin console, Thank you Diego.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your usecase, what you likely wanna do is transfer the files using the [Data Transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/reference/rest/v1/transfers#DataTransfer) , this would transfer the ownership of the files and leave the previous owner as an Editor, so both users would be able to access the files but the files would have a new owner, and when the previous owner been deleted that would have no effect over the files.

The transfer would produce a new folder under the the new owner "My Drive" with the username of the previous owner.

Comment: Thank you Vasil! this really helped a lot